# What happens when I define a virtual method as private?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, virtual-functions

given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class classA {
    virtual void virtualMethod() {
        cout << "classA" << endl;
    }
public:
    virtual ~classA() {
        virtualMethod();
    }
    void mA() {
        virtualMethod();
    }
};

class classB: public classA {
    void virtualMethod() override {
        cout << "classB" << endl;
    }
public:
    ~classB() override {
        virtualMethod();
    }
    void mB() {
        virtualMethod();
    }
};
int main(void) {
    classA* obj = new classB;
    obj->mA();
    obj->mB(); // *** why I really get here error?
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

I will be happy to understand what happens in any line that exists in the main, and in addition what is happens while `obj` deleted in the end running of the `main` function. I don't want to know just the answer: "the output is ...." , but, to understand why it's so.

My problem is mainly to understand the case that we at `mA` method. To where we are going from there?  It seems that we should go to `classA::virtualMethod` because that `classB::virtualMethod` is a private method at `classB` and hence, we don't meet it from `classA` (but while I running the code, I find that it's not correct, and I do not understand why).

In addition, I will be happy to understand why I get error in the line `obj->mB();`, according to the compiler, the reason is:

> 'class classA' has no member named 'mB'

But why it's not going according to `classB` (After all, we did `new classB`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member name visibility is based on the *declared* type of the object or pointer. Since `obj` is declared to be of type `ClassA*`, only the member names in `ClassA` are visible. And outside the class, only the public members are visible.

This is because a pointer to `ClassA` can point to an object of the base class or any of its derived classes. It would not make sense to allow you to call `obj->mB()`, since `obj` might not actually point to an object that has a `mB()` member function. We have to be able to determine at compile time whether the name is valid, and that can only depend on the type declaration, not the value.

The rule for virtual methods only come into play *after* allowing visibility. When calling a virtual method through a pointer, it uses the *actual* type of the object that it points to to find the method to call. At runtime it goes up the derivation tree to find the most derived class that defines the method, and uses that.

Comment: `"the rule for virtual methods only come into play after allowing visibility. When calling a virtual method through a pointer, it uses the actual type of the object that it points to....................."`  , So why while we deletes the object it's prints `classA`?

Comment: Constructors and destructors are automatically called for all the classes in the hierarchy. So it prints both classB and classA.

Comment: This is a *much* nicer way of putting these concepts to the OP than my attempt.

Comment: We going from the destructor of `classB` to `classB::virtualMethod()` , ok I understand it. But, after this, we going to `~classA()` , and why from there we going to `classA::virtualMethod()` and not to `classB::virtualMethod()` ?

Comment: When you get to the `classA destructor`, the `classB` part of the object has been destroyed, so it only uses the `classA` method.

Comment: Ohh, now it's clear. Thank you about your amazing answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The private `virtualMethod` in class `classB` is reachable via any function in `classA` because it's marked as `virtual` in `classA` (Note that Java does not allow this, but C++ does).

`obj` is a pointer of type `classA`. `classA` does *not* have a method called `mB`, `virtual` or otherwise, so it's not reachable via that pointer.

Comment: Given method that defined as a `virtual` in some class, so, we will can going to the method that overrides it , from any method that defined in the "base class"?